# how to remove complete node js and npm from Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: nodejs, npm

although I try with all nodejs uninstall command, still node version and npm version is showing when I run **npm -v**
I run followingh commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs

sudo apt-get remove npm
sudo apt-get update



sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d ~/.npm ~/.node-gyp /opt/local/bin/node /opt/local/include/node /opt/local/lib/node_modules 

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node*

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node*

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node*
```

**List item**

Comment: How did you install `nodejs`, from source or from the repository (apt-get)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try running `apt-get remove nodejs --purge` and `apt-get remove npm --purge`.

If the command continues to run, you can run `find / -name npm`, check the results, and delete files that you consider necessary.

Answer (score 0):

To manually remove node js, npm and  node_modules from Ubuntu,  you need to do the following steps.

1. First of all you need to run the following command from command terminal as sudo.

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d ~/.npm ~/.node-gyp /opt/local/bin/node opt/local/include/node /opt/local/lib/node_modules

2. Remove node or node_modules directories from /usr/local/lib with the help of following command.

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node*

3. Remove node or node_modules directories from /usr/local/include with the help of following command.

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node*

5. Remove any node file or dir from /usr/local/bin with the help of following command.

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node*

4. Go to home directory and remove any node or node_modules directory, if exists.

Now it is done